# Split strings into a set of grouped array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

Suppose I have two string:

```
Hello,C#,Black,March
World,Java,White,April
```

I want to split them and group them together into an array (maybe 2-dimensional array).
E.g.

```
 { "Hello", "World"}
 { "C#", "Java"}
 { "Black", "White"}
 { "March", "April" }
```

My attempt:

```
string[] arr1 = str1.Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim()).ToArray();
string[] arr2 = str2.Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim()).ToArray();

if (arr1.Length == arr2.Length)
{
   string[,] groupedValue = new string[arr1.Count(), arr2.Count()];
   //groupedValue[0, 0] = ...
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Usage of Linq [Zip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx) makes sense here:

```
string str1 = "Hello,C#,Black,March";
string str2 = "World,Java,White,April";

string[][] result = str1.Split(',')
                        .Zip(
                            str2.Split(','),
                            (s1, s2) => new string[] { s1, s2 }
                         )
                        .ToArray();
```

`Zip()` iterates both result arrays of `Split()` and creates for each index a new array `(s1, s2) => new string[] { s1, s2 }` containing both items of the current index.